# errorPlacement can not be validate in first call but work fine in second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, errorplacement

using following function for validating but cant be work fine in first time but work fine in second time.
second function is used for validator and its not working fine when i first click the button but its work fine second time please help.

```
function saveValue(){
 if (validateFormset().form()) { // validation perform
     $('form#vendorActionForm').attr({methos: 'POST'});
     $('form#vendorActionForm').attr({action: 'vendorAddressCreateUpdate.htm'});
     $('form#vendorActionForm').submit();
 }else{
     $(".textMessgeClass").text("Please fill the highlighted field/s");
     $(".textMessgeClass").addClass('errorClass');
     $(".textMessgeClass").fadeIn("slow");
     $(".textMessgeClass").delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
 }
}

function  validateFormset(){
    var validator = $("#vendorActionForm").validate({
 rules: {
     accountType: {
         required:true
     },
     addressRank: {
         required:true
     },
     street: {
         required:true
     },
     city: {
         required:true
     },
     state: {
         required: true,
         accept: "[a-zA-Z]+",
         minlength: 2
     },
     region: {
         required: true
     },
     zipCode: {
         required: true,
         rangelength: [3, 5]

     },
     contactName: {
         required: true
     },
     mobile: {
         required: false,
         number: true,
         minlength: 10
     },
     email: {
         required: true,
         email: true
     },
     email2: {
         required: false,
         email: true
     },
     email3: {
         required: false,
         email: true
     }

    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).filter(':not(.valid)').addClass("addressErrorClass");            
    },
    success: function(error) {
        $("#vendorActionForm").find('.valid').removeClass("addressErrorClass");
    }
    });
    alert('AAAA');
    alert(validator);
    return  validator;
}
```

Comment: Function names is missing `function (){
 if (validateFormset().form()) { //` in mentioned statements...

Comment: actually its just for demo function saveValue(){ } is used.